# Seeing data sent by the browser without firebug

Tags: browsers, post

is there any way to see the data sent by the browser without firebug? Some other tool? I need to see which data is sent by the browser in some websites and the firebug console sometimes is blank. I've read somewhere that if the script writes to the console variable , the console wont show anything.

Comment: Have you tried [chrome dev tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading)?

Comment: does that appear when you hit F12? Because now I have firebug installed and firebug for Google Chrome opens when I do that

Comment: Yes it appears when I hit F12(And I have not installed firebug in my chrome), but you can get same setting by doing these steps -  Right click anywhere in your webpage, and select inspect option, then go to network option.

Comment: have you checked for websockets ?